# Logic of SQL Query kindly help me out

Tags: sql, oracle, select

If a column contains a certain value (for example, `SEEMA`), what method might one to use to determine how many times the letter `E` occurs in that value?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  You should include sample data and desired results, at a minimum.  A SQL Fiddle example is really useful.

Answer (score 1):

[`regexp_count`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions135.htm#SQLRF20014) should do the trick:

```
SELECT col, REGEXP_COUNT(col, 'E')
FROM   some_table
WHERE  col LIKE '%SEEMA%'
```